# Are orbits of a measurable flow always measurable with measure zero?

Tags: pr.probability, ergodic-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X, \mathcal{B})$ be a standard Borel space with a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}$. Let $(T_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ be a jointly measurable flow (i.e. $(T_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a group of Borel automorphisms and $(t, x) \mapsto T_t(x)$ is measurable as a map from $\mathbb{R} \times X \rightarrow X$). Suppose that $(T_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ preserves the measure $\mu$ and assume that $\mu$ has no point masses.

**Questions:**

(1) Is it always the case that, for any choice of $x \in X$, we have $\mu(\{T_t(x): t \in \mathbb{R}\}) = 0$?

(2) If not, is it at least true that, for any $x \in X$, $\{T_t(x): t \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset B \in \mathcal{B}$ with $\mu(B) = 0$?

**Thoughts:** If I'm reading it correctly, (2) follows from W. Ambrose, "[Representation of Ergodic Flows](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969259)", pp. 736--737. The argument involves splitting $X$ into countably many disjoint measurable subsets, on which the flow is either completely non-ergodic or ergodic, and using the fact that ergodic flow is isomorphic to a flow built under a function.

Comment: What about $X=\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$ and $T_t(x) = x+t$?

Comment: This is basically case 2) on the bottom of p.736

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle: ah, thanks! Do you think it's crucial for examples of this kind to work that we've got X with topological dimension one?

Comment: @Asaf: right. But then, at the top of p. 736 he considers the case where every point is measurable and of measure 0 ("the usual case", as he says). And he seems to be saying that in this case each trajectory is measurable and of measure 0?

Comment: @StepanPlyushkin, I am not sure what you are reading, nor going to read the whole article. The bottom of p. 736 summarizes the theorem. Notice that in the ergodic case, the orbit (not its closure) is an $S_{t}$-invariant set, hence it will be of null measure or conull measure. Also, it is clear that ON THE ORBIT, the action is isomorphic to translation over $\mathbb{R}$.

Also your $(2)$ doesn't make sense, for a generic point, in the ergodic case, for any $B$, the set of return times to $B$ would be unbounded with a density equal to $\mu(B)$.

Comment: @Asaf great, thanks! My (2) was intended to read: for any $x \in X$, there's some $B \subset \mathcal{B}$ with $\mu(B) = 0$ such that $\{T_t(x): t \in \mathbb{R}\} \subseteq B$. But this is only to say that each orbit is of null measure with respect to the completed measure. And that **can** happen in the case of an ergodic flow, yes?

Comment: First of all it is a bit dangerous to change completions in Ergodic Theory. 
Second, I don't understand the notion of ${T_{t}(x): t\in\mathbb{R}}\subset B$. Do you mean the set of return times? Maybe this set is empty?
 
Whatever this notion of yours is, if that's for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, the set $B$ is $T_{t}$-invariant, hence of null measure or conull measure.. At any case, you will always need to worry about the system being Kronecker, as Mikael alluded to. In the Kronecker case, for any $x$, the only possible set $B$ (if I understand correctly) must be $X$.